What's the name of this film about 9.11?
I can't remember the name of a film. I'm not sure wether it is a documentary or a film. I saw it on my computer a few years ago.
It is a reconstitution of the reactions of FAA and US army on 9.11. I clearly remember a guy (at FAA) ordering to close the airspace, and another (in the army) complaining about the fact F16 were not ready, and then sent the wrong way.
Will you have more memory than I have?

There are a number of films that concern this topic. However, United 93 (2006) is a better-known dramatization that extensively deals with the FAA and the military's reaction.
